# Selecting layer for processing

Tags: qgis, export, vector-tiles, mbtiles, pbf

I am currently trying **to export a map as PBF vector tiles** (Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf) details: https://protobuf.dev/ ) but I can't find a way to select the current layer in the toolbox (about Mapbox vector tiles standards:  https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-standards/)

[image]

[image]

I have two layers, one from a mbtiles I imported named new-york and one from clicking on XYZ Tiles / OpenStreetMap ideally I want to export this as tiles

[image]

[image]

It's clear that I'm missing a vital step here but starting new with maps is overwhelming and searching for hours did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert that particular OpenStreetMap layer to vector tiles, it's a raster format.  You  should try to find a vector source for OSM data.

If you use the GDAL->Vector conversion->Convert format tool you can convert the New York mbtiles layer to a vector layer that you can use in the Write vector tiles (XYZ) tool.

Again, you won't be able to select the layer from the map, but you can use the Select File... to add the .mbtiles file directly.

[image]

You'll be able to use the converted vector layer in the Write vector tiles (XYZ) tool.

[image]